# Send Codable Object To Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have the following custom class.

```
class FundingRequest: Codable {
let dispatcherName, loadReference, origin, destination: String
let pickedUp, droppedOff, driverFirstName, driverLastName: String
let grossTruckPay, advancesTaken, fundingMethod, comments: String
let additionalCharges, rateConfirmation, billOfLading, lumperReceipt: [String]
let salesTicket: [String]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case dispatcherName = "DispatcherName"
    case loadReference = "LoadReference"
    case origin = "Origin"
    case destination = "Destination"
    case pickedUp = "PickedUp"
    case droppedOff = "DroppedOff"
    case driverFirstName = "DriverFirstName"
    case driverLastName = "DriverLastName"
    case grossTruckPay = "GrossTruckPay"
    case advancesTaken = "AdvancesTaken"
    case fundingMethod = "FundingMethod"
    case comments = "Comments"
    case additionalCharges = "AdditionalCharges"
    case rateConfirmation = "RateConfirmation"
    case billOfLading = "BillOfLading"
    case lumperReceipt = "LumperReceipt"
    case salesTicket = "SalesTicket"
}

init(dispatcherName: String, loadReference: String, origin: String, destination: String, pickedUp: String, droppedOff: String, driverFirstName: String, driverLastName: String, grossTruckPay: String, advancesTaken: String, fundingMethod: String, comments: String, additionalCharges: [String], rateConfirmation: [String], billOfLading: [String], lumperReceipt: [String], salesTicket: [String]) {
    self.dispatcherName = dispatcherName
    self.loadReference = loadReference
    self.origin = origin
    self.destination = destination
    self.pickedUp = pickedUp
    self.droppedOff = droppedOff
    self.driverFirstName = driverFirstName
    self.driverLastName = driverLastName
    self.grossTruckPay = grossTruckPay
    self.advancesTaken = advancesTaken
    self.fundingMethod = fundingMethod
    self.comments = comments
    self.additionalCharges = additionalCharges
    self.rateConfirmation = rateConfirmation
    self.billOfLading = billOfLading
    self.lumperReceipt = lumperReceipt
    self.salesTicket = salesTicket
}
```

}

I need to be able to send this to my web service which expects it as JSON in a parameter named JSON. Also need to pass a secret called 'code' along with this. Not sure how to acheive this using alamofire.

This is what I've tried so far but it didn't work, I'm not doing it right at all.

```
r fundingReqeust = FundingRequest(dispatcherName: txtDispatcherName.text!, loadReference: txtLoadReference.text!, origin: txtOrigin.text!, destination: txtDestination.text!, pickedUp: txtPickedUp.text!, droppedOff: txtDroppedOff.text!, driverFirstName: txtDriverFirstName.text!, driverLastName: txtDriverLastName.text!, grossTruckPay: txtGrossTruckPay.text!, advancesTaken: "0", fundingMethod: "1", comments: txtComments.text!, additionalCharges: additionalChargesString, rateConfirmation: rateConfirmationsURL, billOfLading: billOfLadingsURL, lumperReceipt: lumperReceiptsURL, salesTicket: SaleTicketURL)
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        let jsonData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(fundingReqeust)
        let json:String = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)! // the data will be converted to the string
        let urlString = "https://xxx.xxx.com"
        let parameters: Parameters = ["code": "xxx", "JSON": json]

        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)

                break
            case .failure(let error):

                print(error)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should pass your data like this:  **let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(ratings)
        request.httpBody = jsonData**

Comment: I have a few style-quibbles about this code, but its basic approach seems fine. What do you mean be "it didn't work?"

Comment: Sorry I understand that's not very helpful. I am able to get the request working when I'm testing in postman, my problem is when I'm building the request I have no idea what it looks like or why it's wrong, I just know it's wrong somewhere as it doesn't work as in postman.

Comment: Did you tried to pass your request in body like : request.httpBody = jsonData?

Answer (score 1):

Does your server accepting the data in the format `["code": "xxx", "JSON": json]`? I am not sure about it but I think it is like `["code": "xxx", "key1": "val1", "key2" : "val2"]`

Try with:

```
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    var jsonData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(fundingReqeust) as? [String: Any]
    jsonData?["code"] = "xxx"
    let urlString = "https://xxx.xxx.com"

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: jsonData, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        response in

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try the below code :**

```
func postRatingReviewDetail(ratings:RatingFeedbackModal, completion:@escaping RatingFeedbackCompletionHandler){

    let urlString = WEBAPI.rating
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    let authString = "Bearer " + TTUserDefalut.getAccessToken()!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue(authString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    do {
        **let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(ratings)
        request.httpBody = jsonData**
    }
    catch let error{
        print("Error", error)
        return
    }
    let _ = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let responseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(RatingResponse.self, from: data)
            completion(responseData,response,error)
        }
        catch{
             completion(nil,nil,nil)
        }

        }.resume()
}
```